# Input text and press enter with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this field

```
 <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi" id="s2id_multiValueSelect" style="width: 300px">    \
     <ul class="select2-choices"> 
        <li class="select2-search-field">   
        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

I've tried using `getElementsByClassName` with `innerHTML` and then `.submit()`, but that didn't work.
It tells me the object has no method submit

Any tips?

edit: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
select2

Comment: What are you trying to do and what's your js-code?

Comment: did you put a <form> around it?

Comment: submit the form not the input field

Comment: uh its not actually a form more of a field

Comment: You cant submit fields without a form..?

Comment: one second i'm doing an edit

Comment: No, you can't submit an input field without form ... How should the browser know where to send the data to? You could read the input's value via JavaScript and send an ajax request or create a manual request, though ...

Comment: well this field itself is already tied into the system. if you type in and press enter it works fine. now i'm just trying to make the word be typed in when i click on it in a visualization

Answer (score 2):

You can only `submit()` a form. So even if it is just one text input field, you still need to wrap it in `<form>` tags and submit via the form id.

```
<form action="path/to/handler" method="POST" id="my-form">
  <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi" id="s2id_multiValueSelect" style="width: 350px">
    <ul class="select2-choices"> 
      <li class="select2-search-field">   
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="select2-input select2-default" style="width: 300px;">
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just a hint: For "submit on enter", a submit button must be present for some browsers (can't remember which one right now :-P). The button may be hidden, though.

Comment: in this case i'm not using form i'm using select2 i provided link, not sure if it works differently

Comment: As I've said, you cannot submit anything other than a `form`... This is your issue, so no need to downvote.

Comment: i didn't downvote anyone, but like i said above i already send my queries successfuly by typing in the text box and pressing enter. now i'm just trying to access it from a visualization

Comment: Yep, select2 is merely sophisticated styling ... the answer is correct.

Comment: no i agree my point was there is already a form somewhere in the system so no need to make new one. it just works slightly differently because instead of using POST to a web page there's some sort of listener which sends info to an internal server

Comment: ok makes sense i'll see if i can find where the form is located

Comment: @Lemonio Yes. Go to your developer console. Find the form. Get the id and target it in your JavaScript using the methods you've already been using. So something like `document.getElementById("the-form-i-finally-found").submit()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Also put the field in a form.